# Can't scrape a static name from a webpage using Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, cheerio

When I try to scrape `Kerri Hughes` from this [webpage](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acschembio.1c00993) using the following script built upon google apps, I always get `Info` as result. The name is static and available in page source (ctrl + u) but still the script fails to grab it. How can I fix it?

```
function myFunction() {
  var options = {
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like  Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36",
     }
   };

  var webURL = "https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acschembio.1c00993";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL,options);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText()); 

  var sName = $("span.hlFld-ContribAuthor").first().text();
  console.log(sName);
}
```

Comment: Log the  response text you're receiving before loading it in cheerio  and see if that html contains the data you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guessed that in your URL, the cookie might be required to be used. So, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var webURL = "https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acschembio.1c00993";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL, { followRedirects: false });
  var options = { headers: { "Cookie": JSON.stringify(res.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"]) } };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL, options);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  var sName = $("span.hlFld-ContribAuthor").first().text();
  console.log(sName); // Kerri Hughes
}
```

#### Result:

When I tested the above script, I confirmed the value of `Kerri Hughes` in the log.

#### Note:

- As another modification, you can also use the following modification. In this modification, the redirected URL and cookie retrieved from the 1st request are used. By this, it seems that the response speed is just a little fast. The same result is obtained.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var webURL = "https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acschembio.1c00993";
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL, { followRedirects: false });
      var resHead = res.getHeaders();
      var options = { headers: { "Cookie": resHead["Set-Cookie"] } };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(resHead["Location"], options);
      var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
      var sName = $("span.hlFld-ContribAuthor").first().text();
      console.log(sName); // Kerri Hughes
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)